# How to replace part of a string taken from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, random

I am trying to take a string from one array and replace a specific part of it with a string from another array. 
Bcards_array is the first array, and the part I want to replace is the "_______" with a full element from Wcard_array.
I currently have:

```
# (the array as a block of text, with each desired element separated by <>)
Wcards_array = Wcards.split("<>")
```

Wcards_array original string found here: http://www.cardsagainsthumanity.com/wcards.txt

```
def random_items(array)
      array.sample(1 + rand(array.count))
    end

Wcard_answer = Wcards_array.sample(1)

Bcard_answer = Bcards_array.sample(1)
Bcard_answer = Bcard_answer.split(" ")
Bcard_answer = Bcard_answer.map! { |element|
   if(element == "__________")
       "#{Wcard_answer}"
   end
}
```

I am currently getting back a No Method error for split, despite using it earlier on

Wcards is linked in comments

Comment: Would be helpful to see what `Wcards` or similar looks like.

Comment: Its just one long string, many phrases separated by <>'s This is the link if you really want it http://www.cardsagainsthumanity.com/wcards.txt

Comment: You're probably better off putting such a sample string in the question tbh. That's not my dv btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through this a little at a time:

```
Wcard_answer = Wcards_array.sample(1)
```

Wcards_array is an array, and you want to get a random element from it and store it in Wcard_answer, presumably you will get a string class back.

```
Bcard_answer = Bcards_array.sample(1)
```

Same, except for Bcards_array.

```
Bcard_answer = Bcard_answer.split(" ")
```

Now you're saying that you're going to transform the answer from Bcards into an array, split by spaces.  Presumably Bcard_answer looks something like 'Testing one two _____' originally.

If you simply want to replace the underscore string in the chosen array element, the map loop is unnecessary.  Here's a shortened example:

```
rep = '__'
ba = ['Testing __', 'More Testing __']
ws = 'one<>two<>three'
wa = ws.split('<>')

answ = wa.sample
ansb = ba.sample.gsub(rep, wa.sample)
```

Running it a few times we see the randomized result:

```
irb(main):007:0> ansb = ba.sample.gsub(rep, wa.sample)
=> "Testing one"
irb(main):008:0> ansb = ba.sample.gsub(rep, wa.sample)
=> "More Testing one"
irb(main):009:0> ansb = ba.sample.gsub(rep, wa.sample)
=> "Testing one"
irb(main):010:0> ansb = ba.sample.gsub(rep, wa.sample)
=> "Testing one"
irb(main):011:0> ansb = ba.sample.gsub(rep, wa.sample)
=> "Testing three"
```

Comment: Took me a bit to understand your variables but this achieved the result I wanted! `Wcard_answer = Wcards_array.sample
Bcard_answer = Bcards_array.sample.gsub(blank, Wcard_answer)
puts Bcard_answer` is what I ended up with

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Wcards = 'some<>words<>yes<>no'
Wcards_array = Wcards.split("<>")

Wcard_answer = Wcards_array.sample
Bcards_array = ['1','2','3',"hello mate _____",'5']
Bcards_array.map! { |s| s.include?("_____") ? s.gsub(/_____/,Wcard_answer) : s }
```

Comment: my problem is that the "__________" is within longer strings and I only want to replace the "__________" not the whole string, eg. (hello my name is ______)  i want to change to (hello my name is Jim)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't see the text file link you posted until I posted my previous answer.  Here's something you can tinker with, if this is what you're trying to do.

```
require 'net/http'

bcard_http = 'http://cardsagainsthumanity.com/bcards.txt'
wcard_http = 'http://cardsagainsthumanity.com/wcards.txt'

bcard_array = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(bcard_http)).body.split('<>')
wcard_array = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(wcard_http)).body.split('<>')

printf("%s\n", bcard_array.sample.gsub('_' * 10, wcard_array.sample))
```